# Injecting additional dependencies into a class - Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, dependency-injection, di.xml, virtualtype

I am trying to inject additional dependencies into a class. The class in question is:
`\Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View\PersonalInfo`

The construct of this class looks like:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerDataFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Helper\Address $addressHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    Mapper $addressMapper,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Logger $customerLogger,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->coreRegistry = $registry;
    $this->accountManagement = $accountManagement;
    $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
    $this->customerDataFactory = $customerDataFactory;
    $this->addressHelper = $addressHelper;
    $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
    $this->addressMapper = $addressMapper;
    $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
    $this->customerLogger = $customerLogger;

    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

I want to include 3 further classes without the requirement of copying the constructor in my class therefore in my module's di.xml I have:

```
<type name="\Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View\PersonalInfo">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="pricingHelper" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data</item>
            <item name="myHelper" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Helper\helper</item>
            <item name="myCollectionFactory" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\CollectionFactory</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Then my class looks like this:

```
class myClass extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View\PersonalInfo
{

    public function myFunction()
    {

        $collection = $this->myCollectionFactory->create();

    }

}
```

However, it's not working and I get the error of

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function create()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In your `di.xml` file, you are injecting your classes within an array wrapper called `data`.

So if I'm not mistaken to currently access the collection with your di it would be

`$this->data['myCollectionFactory']`

If you were to remove the data array wrapper to access them like you are trying to it would look like so.

```xml
<type name="\Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View\PersonalInfo">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="pricingHelper" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data</argument>
        <argument name="myHelper" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Helper\helper</argument>
        <argument name="myCollectionFactory" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\CollectionFactory</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html#constructor-arguments

---

If you are looking at adding custom functionality to a template, that does not rely upon logic within the block (such as returning a custom collection etc) then another option could potentially be using a view model.

Where you can inject a custom class from XML and access it with `$block->getMyViewModel()`

See: https://www.yireo.com/blog/2017-08-12-viewmodels-in-magento-2